# Strange behavior with Background-image on stock android browser

Tags: android, css, background-image

Whenever I use the below CSS (I also declared it with the shorthand and got same result) I get this strange "BES" that appears for a split second on the page when viewed on certain Android Stock browsers.

```
html { 
  background-image: url(http://www.cynthiapacephotography.com/wp-content/themes/pace_origin/images/background2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Even if I remove all the extras and just leave it like below, I still get the weird letters

```
background-image: url(http://www.cynthiapacephotography.com/wp-content/themes/pace_origin/images/background2.png);
```

I don't get this on the iPhone or Chrome on Android devices.  I finally just added a media query and just using a background color on mobile devices.  With just the background color and no image, I don't get the letters anymore. I also tried a handful of background images and this always happens when using a background image.

Any ideas of what this is and what's causing it?

Here's a shot of what I see:
[image]

Comment: I suspect strongly that your problem is elsewhere in your code.  A png alone won't cause that behavior.  You should search your project for the string "BES and see what show up.

Comment: I would be strongly inclined to agree with you.  But it only happens when I used this style sheet. And I narrowed it down to only happening with the above CSS declaration block is used.  Even more so, it only happens when the background-image declaration is used.
The only other thing  I could think of is if something else is having a bad interaction with the background-image, but I couldn't think of what it would be.